# Jquery TypeError - "$(...).whatever is not a function" when loading two libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, I need some help with this.

This is the code piece that is failing

```
    <!-- Begin Photofolio library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-photostack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#portfolioslider').coinslider({
        width: 480,
        height: 280,
        navigation: false,
        links: false,
        hoverPause: true
    });
    $("#tabcontainer").tabs({
        event: "click"
    });
});
</script>

<!-- End Photofolio -->

<!-- Begin REDX -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/orman/orman.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>
```

And when I load the page, it shows me this error:
TypeError: $(...).coinslider is not a function

I have tried to use "jQuery" identifier, but it didn't work. I don't know if I did ir right, since I just replaced all "$" with "jQuery" and didn't do more than that.

What is wrong in my code?

Regards

Comment: Why are you loading so many different versions of jQuery on that page?

Comment: You should at least remove either `scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js` or `scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js`.  You don't need both.

Comment: I'm all for removing the `scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js`. Especially if you're using 1.6.1, you shouldn't need the older version.

Answer (score 3):

When you use two different versions of jquery (which is not recommended), you can use jQuery.noConflict [api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to check your src="scripts/jquery-coin-slider.min.js" to check what function makes it work. Maybe .coinslider is not inside that js file.